# SQL: [performance] what is faster, Inner joins or equal statement in "where"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, performance

What is the best performing query of the two? I'm looking for a general performance answer :)

```
select count(A.M_XXX_ROUTE)
from 
YY.TRN_HDR_BB C
inner join YY.DLV_CASH_BB A on C.M_NB = A.M_TRD_REF
inner join YY.TABLE#DATA#SITRN_BB B on A.M_XXX_ROUTE = B.M_REF
```

or

```
select count(A.M_XXX_ROUTE)
from 
YY.DLV_CASH_BB A,
YY.TRN_HDR_BB C,
YYY.TABLE#DATA#SITRN_BB B

Where 
C.M_NB=A.M_TRD_REF
and A.M_XXX_ROUTE=B.M_REF;
```

There are only small differences in the performance between the two, but what if i add 50 more joins or where statements?

Comment: Look at execution plans. I think they won't differ, for MySQL at least they must be identical.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: BTW, both are valid ANSI SQL, old and slightly newer versions.

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: Clearly, `JOIN` is faster because you won't be spending your time explaining why your are using outdated, archaic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be the same, because internally, Oracle will recast the ANSI syntax into its own anyway. If I run this:

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select *
  3  from  scott.emp e
  4  inner join scott.dept d
  5  on d.deptno = e.deptno;

Explained.
```

then a trace of what is happening under the covers reveals the query to be

```
Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT "E"."EMPNO" "EMPNO","E"."ENAME" "ENAME","E"."JOB" "JOB","E"."MGR" "MGR","E"."HIREDATE" "HIREDATE",
"E"."SAL" "SAL","E"."COMM" "COMM","E"."DEPTNO" "DEPTNO","D"."DEPTNO" "DEPTNO","D"."DNAME" "DNAME","D"."LOC" "LOC" 
FROM "SCOTT"."EMP" "E","SCOTT"."DEPT" "D" WHERE "D"."DEPTNO"="E"."DEPTNO"
```

That trace is called a "10053" trace, but thats a level of detail you probably don't need to worry about.

Comment: Would you recommend following ANSI standard (inner joins)? it is more readable and less lines of codes?

Comment: "It depends".  For a brand new codebase, people typically recommend ANSI. For an existing codebase, I would say align with what it already there, because mixing-and-matching is probably worse than one or the other.

Comment: @CKO95 - Use the `JOIN..ON` syntax.  Period.  Full stop.

Comment: @RickJames can you elaborate why?

Comment: `JOIN..ON` _should_ be used to tell readers how the tables are related.  `WHERE` _should_ be used for filtering.  Doing so makes it easier for readers to understand the schema and schema.  In the case of `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, picking the appropriate place _does_ make a difference in the functioning of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so there will be any performaqnce difference, you can confirm the same by explain plan.

1st Query is ANSI standard while 2nd is Oracle old way of doing joins.